# Embedding NetGraph EditableGraph in PyQt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, netgraph

I try to embed the `EditableGraph` function into a `PyQt5` application. I developed the following program for testing, based on solutions found online.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from netgraph import EditableGraph, InteractiveGraph
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        self.canvas.ax = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.editgraph = EditableGraph([(0, 1), (1,2), (2,0)], 
                                       ax=self.canvas.ax)

        # Enable key_press_event events:
        self.canvas.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.canvas.setFocus()

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

However I have the following error:

> self.fig.canvas.manager.key_press = key_press_handler AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key_press'

More in detail, the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:... \testit.py", line 26, in <module>
    w = MainWindow()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:... \testit.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.graph = EditableGraph([(0, 1), (1,2), (2,0)], ax=self.canvas.ax)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C: ... \netgraph\_interactive_graph_classes.py", line 1971, in __init__
    self.fig.canvas.manager.key_press = key_press_handler
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key_press'
```

When I exchange `EditableGraph` by `InteractiveGraph`, it works well.

I use the following dev version of `NetGraph`.

```bash
pip install https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/archive/dev.zip
```

I don't know where the problem originated from, and I couldn't find a solution on the Web. Can you please help me? This embedding is crucial for my application. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. The issue is to properly assign a manager to the canvas. First, `matplotlib.figure.Figure` does not produce a manager while `pyplot.figure()` does.
In the following program the result is `None` for `fig1` while it corresponds to an object reference for `fig2`.

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1 = Figure()
fig2 = plt.figure()
print("fig1>",fig1.figure.canvas.manager)
print("fig2>",fig2.figure.canvas.manager)
```

However, merely replacing `Figure()` with `plt.figure()` is insufficient because the `manager` is not copied/exported/transmitted to the canvas. Therefore, this must be achieved explicitly. The final code is as follows:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from netgraph import EditableGraph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        fig = plt.figure() # use pyplot.figure()  instead of Figure()
        
        manager = fig.canvas.manager # keep the manager 
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig) 
        self.canvas.ax = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas.figure.canvas.manager = manager # <-- assign the manager to the canvas figure.
        self.graph = EditableGraph([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)], ax=self.canvas.ax)

        self.canvas.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.canvas.setFocus()

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The creation of a matplotlib canvas in PyQT5 is typically defined by a class. Here is the definition of such a class including the manager:

```
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg)
def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=5, dpi=100):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
    manager = fig.canvas.manager
    self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
    super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)
    self.figure.canvas.manager = manager
    self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1)
```